# Symfony 5 - Object of class App\Entity\Vegetal could not be converted to string

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I have a problem when trying to add an image to a folder on a website that I'm developping currently. When I try to rename the file, I would like it to be : idOfMyObject.jpg

But when I want to add it on my form, this error code pops up : "Object of class App\Entity\Vegetal could not be converted to string".

The problem's apparently inside the isset, but I can't find a solution to convert my id to string.

Here is the Controller :

```
public function ajouterVegetal(Request $request): Response
    {   
        $fFeuille = new FormeFeuille();
    
        $vegetal = new Vegetal();
        $formVegetal = $this->createForm(VegetalType::class, $vegetal);
        $formVegetal->handleRequest($request);

        //Si le formulaire est bien valide (tous les champs remplis) et que le bouton submit est appuyé
        if ($formVegetal->isSubmitted() && $formVegetal->isValid()) { 
            //on récupère les données du formaulaire
            $vegetal = $formVegetal->getData();
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            
            //on récupère les données de la variable image dans le formulaire d'ajout     
            $fileDownload = $formVegetal['images']->getData();
            //si le fichier existe, on le renomme avec l'id du végétal, pour le sauvegarder dans le dossier configuré dans service.yaml
            if (isset($fileDownload))
            {
                $nomImage = $fFeuille->getVegetals()->{$this->$vegetal->getId()}.'.'.$fileDownload->guessExtension();         
                $fileDownload->move(
                     $this->getParameter('upload_directory'),
                     $nomImage
                );
            }
            //on ajoute les données dans la base
            $entityManager->persist($vegetal);
            $entityManager->flush();

            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();      

            return $this->redirectToRoute('listerVegetal');
        } else {
            return $this->render('Vegetal/ajouterVegetal.html.twig', [
                'vegetal' => $vegetal,
                'form' => $formVegetal->createView(),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `{$this->$vegetal ... }` tries to convert `$vegetal` to a string value and then tries to access that value on `$this`. You probably need to remove the `$this->` or change to `$this->vegetal`, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Which of these lines causes that problem? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I will allow myself to assume that this error is caused when rendering the form.
And most likely you are using EntityType for Vegetal in formBilder. I'm guessing that when you render the form, you get this error because formBilder tries to convert Vegetal to render it in "select", but it fails because it doesn't know what value to take.

---

The code below will just help php decide what value to return when converting this object to a string.

Add in Entity `Vegetal`

```
public function __toString(): string
{
    return $this->getName();  // or some string field in your Vegetal Entity 
}
```

---

It also might not work for you, but usually my similar errors were solved by this.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that this makes sense in the given context?

Comment: There is too little information in the question, because of this I will assume that this error will occur when creating the form.
Most likely, the form uses the EntityType for the Vegetal entity. This kind of error usually occurs when symfony tries to get a string to output in the select when rendering the form. If I'm wrong, then I'm sorry)

Comment: If there is too little information in the question to write a proper answer, you should ask for clarification and wait for it before writing an answer that assumes a lot of stuff, but does not put any context around your assumption. How should the OP evaluate whether your solution makes sense or not, if you havent explained what it could help with?

Comment: I assumed that this answer would solve the problem, since I encountered this many times. What is the problem? You can't be 100% sure it's wrong.

Comment: Then please add an explanation to your answer such that others can understand **why** this could help to resolve the problem. I would assume that your code would throw a new error, as the line `$fFeuille->getVegetals()->{$this->$vegetal->getId()}` would now call `getId()` on a string

Comment: No, when you add the toString() magic method, the object will not become a default string.
This method will just tell php what to output if for some reason it needs to get a string from an object.

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your answer by editing it. What's the difference between a "default string" and the string that your `__toString()` method returns?